# Sorting names not working properly for list items?

Tags: string, sorting, twitter

Here is my sample code,where i'm sorting names but here in result Names with Capital letters are coming first and remaining names with small letters are coming next.But i need all names in Sorting order.Eg:abc,ABC,japan,Jungle,Tokyo,twinkle.
'

`final List<String> names = new LinkedList<>();
            do {

                ids = twitter.getFriendsIDs(name, cursor);
                for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {
                    //out.println(id + ":");
                    User user = twitter.showUser(id);
                    names.add(user.getName());
                    //out.println(user.getName());

                    String imgUri = user.getProfileImageURL();

                }
            } while ((cursor = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0);
            Collections.sort(names);
             for (String Sname : names) {
                out.println(Sname);
            }`
'

Could anybody tell me where to change my code.

Answer (score 0):

`compareTo()` method is defined in interface java.lang.Comparable and it is used to implement natural sorting on java classes. natural sorting means the the sort order which naturally applies on object e.g. lexical order for String, numeric order for Integer. However there are certain basics to remember while overriding `compareTo`

- It should return negative number if the current object is less than the object, appositive value if it is greater and zero if both the objects are equal
- Make sure it is consistent with `equals()`

You could create a class MyString as

```
public class MyString implements Comparable{
  private String myString;
  public boolean compareTo(Object o){ 
    // TODO 
  return false;
 }
}
```